# ViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning Bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, uimodalpresentationstyle

I am presenting a viewController with `modalPresentationStyle` set to `UIModalPresentationCustom` and with my custom `transitioningDelegate`. I successfully tested a non-interactive transition at first, then I wanted to go deeper and add an interactiveTransition, but only for dismissal.

[[VIDEO] iOS7 custom transitioningDelegate demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybf1ywk1dt3nwsv/AppBug.mov?dl=0)

The demo video speaks for itself, as you can see in iOS7 when touch event triggers `interactiveTransitioning` and I cancel the dismissal, if I try to rotate, the presentedViewController has unexpected behaviour and goes fullscreen, otherwise the rotate works as it should.

I noticed that before rotating, if the `interactiveTransitioning` was triggered, in the mainViewController `- willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` the `self.presentedViewController` is `nil`, which is obviously a bug.

How can I fix this?

Note: in iOS8 ALL works perfectly, and the `self.presentedViewController` is never nilled out when it is not the case!